# How to use "START WITH CONNECT BY NOCYCLE" on a column contains comma separator values?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having a scenario in which there is table name: UserMaster which contains two column first is UserId and second is BackUpUsers.

In UserId column i am having 6 data rows which are | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

In BackUpUsers column i am having 6 corresponding rows which can contains values in comma separator fields which are: | null | 3, 4 , 6 | null | null| null | null |

So in previous scenario if i don't use comma separator values functionality was working fine by below query:

SELECT UserId FROM UserMaster START WITH UserId = 3 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR UserId = BackUpUsers;

In above query first it select the row of UserId 3 and search its UserId through out the table into the BackUpUsers column and if found then taking it's UserID search it into BackUpUsers column again and so on.

It was previously working fine but due to one to one data mapping but after implementing comma separated value it is not working fine for which i have also tried using INSTR as below query but not working as expected:
SELECT UserId FROM UserMaster U START WITH U.UserId = 3 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE INSTR(BACKUPUSRS, ',' || PRIOR u.USRCOD || ',') > 0

So what should i modify/add so that it will work as expected.. any help or suggestion will be highly welcome....

Comment: What DB engine do you use? Don't just tag all of them.

Comment: Thanks @juergend i have removed the remaining unnecessary tags.. i am using oracle sql developer.

Comment: Your question is still tagged MySQL. For MySQL the solution will be completely different than Oracle. Which one is it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma-separated values are very bad design. You should reconsider this decision and reconsider, unless you change it :)

If I understood right, you means 'record #2 has children: #3, #4 and #6'. If so, you should use something like

```
select userid
from usermaster
start with userid = 3
connect by (',' || prior backupusers || ',') like ('%,' || userid || ',%')
```